# aligning icons in top_links.phtml

Tags: toplinks

I have a problem with aligning the content of my top_links.phtml

Using the Ultimo theme, I have added flags to the store switcher using the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Language switcher template
 *
 * @see Mage_Page_Block_Switch
 *
 */
?>
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
    <?php
        $currStoreName = '';
        $currStoreCode = '';
        $html = array();
        $html[] = '<ul class="dropdown-menu left-hand">';
        foreach($this->getStores() as $_store)
        {
            $storeName = $this->__($this->escapeHtml($_store->getName()));
            $storeId = $_store->getId();
            $storeCode = $_store->getCode(); //$storeCode = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $storeId);
            $css = 'style="background-image:url('. $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/'. $storeCode .'.png') .');"';

            if($storeId == $this->getCurrentStoreId())
            {
                $currStoreName = $storeName;
                $currStoreCode = $storeCode;
                $html[] = '<li class="current"><span class="label dropdown-icon" '. $css .'>&nbsp;</span>'. $storeName .'</li>';
            }
            else
            {
                $html[] = '<li><a href="'. $_store->getCurrentUrl() .'"><span class="label dropdown-icon" '. $css .'>&nbsp;</span>'. $storeName .'</a></li>';
            }
        }
        $html[] = '</ul>';
    ?>



<?php if (count($this->getStores()) > 1): ?>
    <div class="form-language">
        <div class="langs-wrapper">
            <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
                <?php $selected = $_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId() ?>
                <a class="lang-flag<?php $selected && print ' selected' ?>" href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/' . $_lang->getCode() . '.png');?>"
                        alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>">
                </a>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

I have then moved the language switcher to the top_links.phtml using:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language');?>
```

In general, that works. However the alignment when moving to smaller screens is total chaos, as can be seen the image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ3RA.jpg

At ipad size, the icons are a mess. At iphone size, the alignment is not great.

I'm not great at css. Obviously my theme (Ultimo) is doing the responsiveness for the site overall.. but my flags and top links are needing cleaning up.

Any tips on how the flags can be forced to stay together as a block.. and have it better aligned etc?

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say what the exact CSS will be without actually seeing the full site code and trying it, but something like below would be a start:        
.header-regular .right-column .user-menu .en.us, .header-regular .right-column .user-menu .fr_fr {
 position: absolute;
    float: right;
}

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what the exact CSS will be without actually seeing the full site code and trying it, but something like below would be a start:
.header-regular .right-column .user-menu .en.us, .header-regular .right-column .user-menu .fr_fr {
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
}